# Can Intellij recognize unused instantiated code in tests?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, findbugs

Intellij, of course, highlights my unused code. If I write something like this in the test:

```
String something= "testValue";
```

`something` will be grayed out.

But , if I have some *instantiation* like:

```
DccData dccData = new DccData();
```

even with

```
dccData.setAmount(12);
```

If `dccData` is never assigned to some other object, my `FindBugs` will eventually find that `dccData` is useless since it is not assigned or used as a return (`thenReturn`), etc. and this will crash my build, because that is how my build is set. I need to keep it that way because of the company's policy.

My question is:

---

> Is there a way for Intellij to notice and gray-out this?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't set "Unused declaration" inspection to trigger `dccData` variable from your sample as unused. It will be difficult to prove that `dccData` is not used anywhere else, i.e. in setter method.